# AVQueuePlayer doesn't play long duration wav audio

Tags: ios, swift, wav, avqueueplayer

I tried playing a `.wav` of 7 minutes,17 minutes, 20 minutes works fine, but when trying to play an audio of 1.04 hour it doesn't work.

And I am sure that .wav file I am using is not corrupted since its being used by android app and they are able to get the duration.

While playing 1.04 hour audio it results `.failed` , in below code

```
if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        audioAsset = AVURLAsset.init(url: url)

        if let audioAsset = audioAsset {

            let keys = ["playable"]

               audioAsset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: keys, completionHandler: {

                let playableStatus = audioAsset.statusOfValue(forKey: keys[0], error: nil)
                switch playableStatus {

                case .unknown,  .loading,  .failed,  .cancelled:
                    return

                case .loaded:

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(asset: audioAsset)
                        self.audioPlayer.insert(playerItem, after: nil)
                        self.audioPlayer.play()

                        })
                    }
                    break
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

I tried playing audio 1 Hour without `AVURLAsset` as below code Audio was not playing.

```
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: url)
self.audioPlayer.insert(playerItem, after: nil)
self.audioPlayer.play()
```

It would be very helpful if I get solution for my problem. or possible reason why this happens ?